# run time error 1004 in for-loop

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

The following code is meant to execute the sumif worksheet function on a list of project items and then write the total cash flow for each project on a different sheet called Pipeline.

The worksheet function however generated a run time error 1004 "Method 'Range of object '_Global' failed.

The code has now been modified (see answers below) which fixed the run time error, but still does not generate the desired outcome. I have modified the code myself based on the last answer, but I think I am missing one last bit to make it work. To make it clearer, I have attached a screen shot of what the code currently produces:

[image]

Two things which are still not working: in column B of the sheet I would like to show the project numbers of the projects which exist on the source sheet (in this example, B8 should have value 1, B9 value 2 and B10 value 3 as there are three projects). Then, The list of sums in column H should stop when there no more projects to sum up, instead of returning value 0.

To make it clearer, this is a screenshot of how the Pipeline sheet looks like:

[image]

Any help please? New Code below:

```
    Sub Write_Pipeline()
    'Sums up revenue of each project in the Input section to display expected cash flow
    Dim ip As Worksheet, pl As Worksheet, Start As Range, Length As Integer, Cnt As Integer, PH As Integer
    Dim SelectRange As Excel.Range
    Dim SumRange As Excel.Range
    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    Set ip = Worksheets("Input")
    Set pl = Worksheets("Pipeline")
    Set Start = pl.Range("B8")
    Start = 1
    Cnt = 1
    Length = 151
    Set SelectRange = ip.Range("B26:B151")
    Set SumRange = ip.Range("Y26:Y151")

    For Each cell In pl.Range("H8").Resize(Length)
        cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(SelectRange, Start, SumRange)
        PH = Start.Value
        Start = Start.Offset(1, 0)
        Start = PH + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you have a few oddities.

Is "ActiveCell" actually a named range ? If that is the case that's a confusing name for a named range (active relative to what ?). If that is not the case then you should replace it with `ActiveCell`. You can omit the `.Value` part.

You want to use `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` to move the active cell one row down.

Comment: Ok thanks; `ActiveCell` was not a named range but just the current active cell, so I replaced it. However, the second suggestion with the offset now produces an error (new code see above) - Invalid Use of Property.

Comment: Here. I corrected my code. I forgot that you were using `ActiveCell` and that it is a special case of a Range object. You cannot modify `ActiveCell` exactly like you would modify a regular `Range` object.

Comment: Ok fixed it, thanks. Now the 1004 has come back in `Range(ActiveCell)...` - I am wondering whether the structure of the sumif is the problem?

Comment: You don't need to use `Range()` when using `ActiveCell`. You can just do `ActiveCell = Application.Work...`

Comment: Also if my answer fixed your problem you can upvote / accept it ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code with all the variables declared. This code also eliminates the use of Select and Activate commands, which is a good idea:

```
Sub Write_Pipeline()
Dim ip As Worksheet, pl As Worksheet, Start As Range, Length As Integer, Cnt As Integer
Dim SelectRange As Excel.Range
Dim SumRange As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set ip = Worksheets("Input")
Set pl = Worksheets("Pipeline")
Set Start = pl.Range("B8")
Start = 1
Cnt = 1
Length = 151
Set SelectRange = ip.Range("B26:B151")
Set SumRange = ip.Range("Y26:Y151")

For Each cell In pl.Range("H8").Resize(Length)
    cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(SelectRange, Start, SumRange)
Next cell
End Sub
```

For future reference, note that `Range(ActiveCell)` attempts to refer to the range whose name or address is in the ActiveCell. This is because, at least in this case, the default value of a range is its `Value`, i.e, `Range(ActiveCell.Value)`. So unless the active cell contains something like "A1" or "B22" (or the name of a range) this will raise a runtime error 1004. And even if it does contain a value like that, I doubt you'd like the result :).

I don't see that you need the `cnt` variable, but I left it in the code.